# Exception Value: Module "storages.backends.gcloud" does not define a "GoogleCloudMediaStorage" attribute/class

Tags: django, google-cloud-storage

I am working on uploading media file to google cloud storage from my django app running on cloud engine.
But while submitting file, I am keep getting error ***The above exception (module 'storages.backends.gcloud' has no attribute 'GoogleCloudMediaStorage') was the direct cause of the following exception:***.

Following error screen shot and code snippets for more details. Any help on this issue is much appreciated.

[image]

settings.py

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'credential.json'))
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudMediaStorage'
GS_PROJECT_ID = 'project-test'
GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'project-bucket'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'
UPLOAD_ROOT= 'media/cad_files'
MEDIA_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/{}/'.format(GS_BUCKET_NAME)
```

gcloud.py is

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.gcloud import GoogleCloudStorage
from storages.utils import setting
from urllib.parse import urljoin

class GoogleCloudMediaStorage(GoogleCloudStorage):
       """
         Google file storage class which gives a media file path from MEDIA_URL not google generated one.
       """
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if not settings.MEDIA_URL:
                raise Exception('MEDIA_URL has not been configured')
            kwargs['bucket_name'] = setting('GS_BUCKET_NAME', strict=True)
            super(GoogleCloudMediaStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def url(self, name):
            """.url that doesn't call Google."""
            return urljoin(settings.MEDIA_URL, name)
```

views.py

```
def file_upload(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            file = form.save(commit=False) # commit=False Read file but Don't save the file yet
            file.uploaded_file = request.FILES['uploaded_file'] # Read file instance in model parameter
            file.customer = request.user.customer # Get current or logedin user
            file.save()
            file_analyze(file)
            return render(request, '/detail.html', {'jobs': jobs})
    else:
        form = FileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Where is your GoogleCloudMediaStorage class implemented

Comment: Sorry this is first time I am working on uploading file to storage. As shown in the post GoogleCloudMediaStorage class is defined in gcloud.py file. Do I need to call it at any other place ie. models?

Comment: where is that file placed in you project, did you implement it inside of package that is not yours?

Comment: gcloud.py file is under my-project directory where settings.py file reside.

Comment: so why are you trying to set it to 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudMediaStorage' if it is not there

Answer (score 1):

My approach is different for uploading the files to gcp cloud.Maybe my approach can help you.
i have used python library [google-cloud-storage](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/)

first create a function then can used anywhere

```
from google.cloud import storage
import logging

def upload_file_to_bucket(file, filename):

saved_file_url = ''
is_file_uploaded = False
try:
    gcs = storage.Client()
    bucket = gcs.get_bucket('bucket_name')
    blob = bucket.blob(filename) # filename
    blob.upload_from_string(file.read())
    blob.make_public() # to make file public to internet
    saved_file_url = blob.public_url
    is_file_uploaded = True
except Exception as e:
    logging.info(e)

data = {'is_file_uploaded':is_file_uploaded, 'bucket_file_url': saved_file_url}
return data
```

and in your django View

```
file = request.FILES['file']
file_name = file.name
data = upload_file_to_bucket(file, file_name)
```